# Python - Creating dictionary from numpy table to display lists

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

Given the following numpy table

```
GR = [
    ['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
    ['PersonA', '100', '90', '80'],
    ['PersonB', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['PersonC', '45', '56', '67'],
    ['PersonD', '59', '61', '67'],
    ['PersonE', '73', '79', '83'],
    ['PersonF', '89', '97', '101']
     ]
```

I need to create a dictionary named GL that maps names of students to lists of their exam grades. grades should be converted from str to int.

```
Desired Output: {'PersonA':[100, 90, 80], 'PersonB':[88, 99, 111], ect....}
```

Comment: Beside the point, but you're missing a closing bracket to match `GR = [`

Comment: Please add the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies @Charles Landau, my python skill has improved drastically since asking this question.

```
GL = dict() 
     for i in GR[1:]:
          GL[i[0]] = [int(i[1]),int(i[2]),int(i[3])]
     print(GL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a little trouble understanding but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
GL = [
    {x[0]: [int(j) for j in x[1:]]} for x in GR[1:]
]
```

Output:

```
[{'PersonA': [100, 90, 80]},
 {'PersonB': [88, 99, 111]},
 {'PersonC': [45, 56, 67]},
 {'PersonD': [59, 61, 67]},
 {'PersonE': [73, 79, 83]},
 {'PersonF': [89, 97, 101]}]
```

Comment: `like this` with ```, called the "backtick" it is shift+tilde on most western boards

Comment: This is how I was able to return what was being asked, took me a little while to debug but should work: ```GL = dict() for item in GR[1:]: GL[item[0]] = [int(item[1]),int(item[2]),int(item[3])] print(GL)```

Comment: @Mac if you answered your own question (or if you found an answer among the ones here) you should mark it as answered. (You can post an answer to your own question and mark it as the answer, that's allowed)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with Python 3 using `map` to convert the grades from `str`s to `int`s and partial unpacking to split each list into a `person` and their `grades`

```
In [111]: {person: list(map(int, grades)) for person, *grades in GR[1:]}
Out[111]:
{'PersonA': [100, 90, 80],
 'PersonB': [88, 99, 111],
 'PersonC': [45, 56, 67],
 'PersonD': [59, 61, 67],
 'PersonE': [73, 79, 83],
 'PersonF': [89, 97, 101]}
```

Python 2 equivalent

```
{g[0]: map(int, g[1:]) for g in GR[1:]}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1:

```
GR_ = {i[0]: list(map(int, i[1:])) for i in GR[1:]}
```

#### Option 2:

```
GR_ = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], list(map(int, x[1:]))), GR[1:]))
```

#### Output:

```
{'PersonA': [100, 90, 80],
 'PersonB': [88, 99, 111],
 'PersonC': [45, 56, 67],
 'PersonD': [59, 61, 67],
 'PersonE': [73, 79, 83],
 'PersonF': [89, 97, 101]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `GR` is a numpy array (and the use of `a[2,0]` indexing confirms that):

```
In [179]: GR
Out[179]: 
array([['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
       ['PersonA', '100', '90', '80'],
       ['PersonB', '88', '99', '111'],
       ['PersonC', '45', '56', '67'],
       ['PersonD', '59', '61', '67'],
       ['PersonE', '73', '79', '83'],
       ['PersonF', '89', '97', '101']], dtype='<U7')
```

So what you are doing is:

```
In [185]: {row[0]: row[1:] for row in GR[1:]}
Out[185]: 
{'PersonA': array(['100', '90', '80'], dtype='<U7'),
 'PersonB': array(['88', '99', '111'], dtype='<U7'),
 'PersonC': array(['45', '56', '67'], dtype='<U7'),
 'PersonD': array(['59', '61', '67'], dtype='<U7'),
 'PersonE': array(['73', '79', '83'], dtype='<U7'),
 'PersonF': array(['89', '97', '101'], dtype='<U7')}
```

The arrays of strings can easily be converted to integers with:

```
In [186]: {row[0]: row[1:].astype(int) for row in GR[1:]}
Out[186]: 
{'PersonA': array([100,  90,  80]),
 'PersonB': array([ 88,  99, 111]),
 'PersonC': array([45, 56, 67]),
 'PersonD': array([59, 61, 67]),
 'PersonE': array([73, 79, 83]),
 'PersonF': array([ 89,  97, 101])}
```

and on to lists:

```
In [187]: {row[0]: row[1:].astype(int).tolist() for row in GR[1:]}
Out[187]: 
{'PersonA': [100, 90, 80],
 'PersonB': [88, 99, 111],
 'PersonC': [45, 56, 67],
 'PersonD': [59, 61, 67],
 'PersonE': [73, 79, 83],
 'PersonF': [89, 97, 101]}
```

My nomination for the list conversion is:

```
In [188]: {name: [int(i) for i in grades] for name, *grades in GR[1:]}
Out[188]: 
{'PersonA': [100, 90, 80],
 'PersonB': [88, 99, 111],
 'PersonC': [45, 56, 67],
 'PersonD': [59, 61, 67],
 'PersonE': [73, 79, 83],
 'PersonF': [89, 97, 101]}
```